# How to stop a text received from splitting up?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms

I just got my first Smart phone (Galaxy S II) and it splits up texts longer than 160 characters when I receive them. I often forward these long texts. Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 2):

The following may work: download an app called [SMS Backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&hl=en) from Play which backs up texts to Gmail. From there, it should be simple enough to forward.

Answer (score 1):

in my experience the division of texts like this has more to do with the carrier. 
For instance, I am on T-Mo.. and texts I get from other T-Mo users are never split.

This is not a limitation of the device so much as it is a limitation with SimpleMessageSyntax